# How to incorporate youtube into iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, youtube

I have an iPhone app and I want one view to push to a UIWebView maybe that shows search results of youtube videos for a particular search term.  Then I want the user to be able to select the video and play it in app.

I've looked at the youtube tutorials but can't seem to get a good grasp as to how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [put youtube video in application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426361/put-youtube-video-in-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method I use in a view controller with a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

```
- (void)embedYouTubeWithURLString:(NSString *)urlStr {
    CGFloat w = webView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat h = webView.frame.size.height;
    NSString *embed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\""\
    " content=\"initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=%0.0f\"/></head><body "\
    "style=\"background-color:transparent;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object "\
    "width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\" /><param name=\"wmode"\
    "\"value=\"transparent\" /><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\" /><param"\
    " name=\"quality\" value=\"high\" /><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash"\
    "\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" />"\
    "</object></div></body></html>", w, w, h, urlStr, urlStr, w, h];
    [webView loadHTMLString:embed baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Will this have a search results page before the actual video is displayed?

Comment: No, it wont, it is just to start streaming the video once you have the url of the one you want to play.

Comment: Ok, how can I first get a results page based on a string I have, then load the video the user chooses.

Comment: You could prompt the user for a search string, then search for videos with: `http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=<SEARCH_STRING_HERE>`.  Then let the user select one, or parse the results and display a table, etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Call YouTube Video Search Web Service.
2. ParseXML Returned from Search.
3. Build a UITableView from Results - Or, build a javascript UI in UIWebView.
4. Play selected video using this method:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html

Comment: Will this have a search results page before the actual video is displayed?

Comment: The method I'm suggesting requires you to roll your own results page.  But, I think you can use the YouTube API to display results as well.