# How to incorporate YouTube into iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, web-services

We are developing an iPhone app where we need to allow users to search and see videos within the app itself.
I have seen this link
[How to incorporate youtube into iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352631/how-to-incorporate-youtube-into-iphone-app) but I have a doubt. Why can’t we simple use NSURLResponse object to retrieve the response and parse it.?

Are they any other easier approaches to implement this functionality?

Comment: Please-don't-hyphenate-your-titles!

Comment: @PengOne When a question is about iOS, in most cases it should be tagged cocoa-touch instead of cocoa.

Comment: @Bavarious Ok, but how is this relevant to me? I only edited his title. I didn't change his tags. Perhaps you should address the comment to sriram instead.

Comment: @PengOne I can’t find the relevant post on MSO but a single, comprehensive edit is preferred over several minor edits (which can lead to the post being marked as Community Wiki).

Comment: @Bavarious I didn't know that cocoa and cocoa touch are two different things i just started to learn objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN just hit a search URL for youtube and parse the data that you get back. The only problem with that is the app would not remain stable. IF youtube were to change the layout of the page, or the names of the tags your app would more than likely crash or become unresponsive.

Using the API's that YouTube has created for your specific needs, would make the app much more stable.
Its unlikely the API would change without YouTube giving you prior notice which will allow you to make the changes need to your app before the update happens.

Do it right the first time. Heres the API link! :)

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api

Query the server, get the response, and parse the data into a UITableView.

Comment: Thanks Louie for the quick response!